# Values in a dataframe column will not change

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, logistic-regression

I have a data frame where I want to replace the values **'<=50K'** and **'>50K'** in the 'Salary' column with **'0'** and **'1'** respectively. I have tried the replace function but it does not change anything. I have tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work. I am trying to do some logistic regression on the cells but the formulas do not work because of the datatype. The real data set has over 20,000 rows.

> ```
> Age   Workclass   fnlwgt  education   education-num   Salary 
> 39  state-gov    455    Bachelors      13            <=50K 
> 25   private     22      Masters       89             >50K
> ```

```
df['Salary']= df['Salary'].replace(['<=50K'],'0')
df['Salary']
```

This is the error i get when i try to do smf.logit(). See below code. I don't understand why i get an error because **Age** and **education-num** are both int64.

```
mod = smf.logit(formula = 'education-num ~ Age', data= dftrn)

resmod = modelAdm.fit()
```

> ValueError: endog has evaluated to an array with multiple columns that
> has shape (26049, 16). This occurs when the variable converted to
> endog is non-numeric (e.g., bool or str).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and for check purpose I have created a new column, you can always change the same column as well just replace new_column with column;

```
df[df['new_salary']=='<=50K']= 0
df[df['new_salary']=='>50K']= 1
```

Comment: i tried. It gives the same values with the '<=50K' and  '>50K'.                                           ~df[df['Salary']=='<=50K']= 0
df[df['Salary']=='>50K']= 1 
df['Salary']~

Comment: are you using '~' before : df[df['Salary']=='<=50K']= 0 ??

Comment: that was typo. but no i am not using it

Comment: can you show me the output of  df[df['Salary']=='>50K'] 
My guess is that there is space somewhere either at beginning or at end or maybe both just check for it

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9Uve.png

Comment: not that just this : df[df['Salary']=='>50K']

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJpv1.png

Comment: df.columns also

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEqaE.png

Comment: there is some issue with the notebook just restart your notebook read your data source and apply above function again

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first question, you should just use a single square bracket on the left side of the equation.

```
df['Salary']= df['Salary'].replace(['<=50K'],'0')
df['Salary']= df['Salary'].replace(['>50K'],'1')
df['Salary']
```

As for the second part of the question, you are naming the model as `mod` but you are calling the fit function on `modelAdm`.

Anyways those are 2 different questions and should be asked separately in 2 different posts.

Comment: i have tried already, it gives same values. Maybe something is wrong with jupyter notebook.

Comment: I am quite sure this should work, I have tried it on my own jupyter notebook. Could you attach a screenshot?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xgl3.png

Comment: Thanks, I suspect either there is a blank space character, or it is not a string.
Could you run the following for me: print(type(df['Salary'][0])) print(df['Salary'][0]) print(df['Salary'][0] == '<=50K')

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWSuc.png

Comment: Did you make changes to your dataframe? The error return says that there is no 'Salary' column in the dataframe at all.

Comment: No, i did not change. But i found a solution. I replaced the values using the notepad app. It has a replace feature. Now all the values changed.